# Failed to read schema document [XSD] because

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation, ofbiz

I am getting the following error message:

> Failed to read schema document
>   'ofbiz.apache.org/dtds/widget-screen.xsd', because 1) could not find
>   the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element
>   of the document is not `<xsd:schema>`.

I have got a XML file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<screens xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ofbiz.apache.org/dtds/widget-screen.xsd">
    <screen name="ShippingAgreement">
        <section>
            <actions>
                <set field="selectedMenuItem" value="facilityShipment"/>
                <set field="selectedSubMenuItem" value="ShippingContract"/>
            </actions>
            <widgets>
                <decorator-screen name="DelysCommonDecorator" location="${parameters.mainDecoratorLocation}">
                    <decorator-section name="body">

                    </decorator-section>
                </decorator-screen>
            </widgets>
       </section>
    </screen>
</screens>
```

Why can't I validate it against XSD file http://ofbiz.apache.org/dtds/widget-screen.xsd?

Comment: You should ensure you access the ressource `http://ofbiz.apache.org/dtds/widget-screen.xsd` properly.

Comment: The root element is <xs:schema> not <xsd:schema>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to access http://ofbiz.apache.org/dtds/widget-screen.xsd from a browser.  Assuming that you too have access to the XSD specified by `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`, delete the following line from your XML

```
<!DOCTYPE xml>
```

and your XML will be valid against the given XSD.

Comment: I deleted <!DOCTYPE xml> but my xml is not valid.

Comment: I confirmed that it was valid without the `<!DOCTYPE xml>` line before answering using a rock-solid Xerces-J-based validator.  What error message are you receiving, and what validator are you using?

Comment: I receive a error as follows: Failed to read schema document 'http://ofbiz.apache.org/dtds/widget-screen.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>. I used XML Validator of Eclipse 4.4.1 to validate

Comment: What happens when you click on this link: http://ofbiz.apache.org/dtds/widget-screen.xsd

Comment: Then suspect XML Validator of Eclipse 4.4.1.   What I can tell you is that the XML is valid per that XSD when you remove the DOCTYPE line.  Try another tool.

Comment: I also suspect XML Validator of Eclipse 4.4.1. I will try another tool, thank you so much @ kjhughes

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. then i was using Netbeans IDE 11.1, i later installed 11.2 and now it worked.
You can also check [Fix for web.xml errors](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/1266) found it to be resourceful during my search on the web :)